# How To make RecyclerView handle onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Has anyone using RecyclerView found a way to set an onClickListener to items in the RecyclerView?

this my code:

**Pasal_Bab.java**

```
public class Pasal_Bab extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private RecyclerViewEmptySupport rv;
private List<PasalBabModel> mPBH;
private PasalBabAdapter adapter;
private static ArrayList<PasalBabModel> people;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pasal, container, false);

    rv = (RecyclerViewEmptySupport) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_pasal);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    rv.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty));
    rv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();
    mPBH = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String countryCode : locales) {
        Locale obj = new Locale("Pasalxyz", countryCode);
        mPBH.add(new PasalBabModel(obj.getDisplayCountry(), obj.getISO3Country()));
    }

    adapter = new PasalBabAdapter(mPBH);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when collapsed
                    adapter.setFilter(mPBH);
                    return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true; // Return true to expand action view
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    final List<PasalBabModel> filteredModelList = filter(mPBH, newText);
    adapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
    adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
    rv.scrollToPosition(0);
    return false;
}

private List<PasalBabModel> filter(List<PasalBabModel> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<PasalBabModel> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PasalBabModel model : models) {
        final String text = model.getpasalbab_p().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}

}
```

**PasalBabAdapter.java**

```
public class PasalBabAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PasalBabVH> {

private List<PasalBabModel> mPasalBabModel;

public PasalBabAdapter(List<PasalBabModel> mPasalBabModel) {
    this.mPasalBabModel = mPasalBabModel;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PasalBabVH PasalBabVH, int i) {
    final PasalBabModel model = mPasalBabModel.get(i);
    PasalBabVH.bind(model);
}

@Override
public PasalBabVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.pasalbab_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new PasalBabVH(view);
}


public void setFilter(List<PasalBabModel> PasalBabModels) {
    mPasalBabModel = new ArrayList<>();
    mPasalBabModel.addAll(PasalBabModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPasalBabModel.size();
}

public void animateTo(List<PasalBabModel> models) {
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<PasalBabModel> newModels) {
    for (int i = mPasalBabModel.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final PasalBabModel model = mPasalBabModel.get(i);
        if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<PasalBabModel> newModels) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final PasalBabModel model = newModels.get(i);
        if (!mPasalBabModel.contains(model)) {
            addItem(i, model);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<PasalBabModel> newModels) {
    for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final PasalBabModel model = newModels.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = mPasalBabModel.indexOf(model);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

public PasalBabModel removeItem(int position) {
    final PasalBabModel model = mPasalBabModel.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    return model;
}

public void addItem(int position, PasalBabModel model) {
    mPasalBabModel.add(position, model);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final PasalBabModel model = mPasalBabModel.remove(fromPosition);
    mPasalBabModel.add(toPosition, model);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
}
}
```

**PasalBabVH.java**

```
public class PasalBabVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView p_TextView;
public TextView b_TextView;

public PasalBabVH(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    p_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.uud_pasal);
    b_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.uud_bab);
}

public void bind(PasalBabModel mx) {
    p_TextView.setText(mx.getpasalbab_p());
    b_TextView.setText(mx.getpasalbab_b());
}

}
```

**PasalBabModel.java**

```
public class PasalBabModel {

String pasalbab_p;
String pasalbab_b;

public PasalBabModel(String pasalbab_p, String pasalbab_b) {
    this.pasalbab_p = pasalbab_p;
    this.pasalbab_b = pasalbab_b;
}


public String getpasalbab_p() {
    return pasalbab_p;
}

public String getpasalbab_b() {
    return pasalbab_b;
}
}
```

please helpme...i'm a beginner :)

Comment: Go through this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: thanks, but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

Create the adapter like so:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Custom.ViewHolder> {

    private List<SomeObject> mDataSet;
    public OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<SomeObject> myDataset, OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mDataSet = myDataset;
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void updateData(List<SomeObject> mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mDataSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        final SomeObject obj = mDataSet.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(obj.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.naam);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If not long clicked, pass last variable as false.
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition(), false, mDataSet);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // If long clicked, passed last variable as true.
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition(), true, mDataSet);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick, List<SomeObject> mFilteredList);
    }
}
```

And set the adapter like this:

```
 mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), dataSet, new CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick, List<SomeObject> mDataSet) {
            if (isLongClick) {
                //Long click
                SomeObject obj = mDataSet.get(position);
            } else {
                //Normal click
                SomeObject obj = mDataSet.get(position);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces to handle onClicks.

Put this in the adapter:

```
 public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClickItem(View view, int position);
    }
  public void SetOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }
```

and then in view holder do this:

```
public class PasalBabVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { 

public TextView p_TextView;
public TextView b_TextView;

public PasalBabVH(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    p_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.uud_pasal);
    b_TextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.uud_bab);
p_TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mItemClickListener != null) {

                    }
                }
            });
b_TextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mItemClickListener != null) {

                    }
                }
            });
} 

public void bind(PasalBabModel mx) {
    p_TextView.setText(mx.getpasalbab_p());
    b_TextView.setText(mx.getpasalbab_b());
} 

}
```

In fragment do this:

```
adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(new PasalBabAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClickItem(View view, int position) {
}});
```